# Can we authenticate a user in azure ad without using graph api

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory

Can we authenticate a user in azure active directory without calling the graph API?
Simply like this, I have my own login screen (which I am planning to do as a web page) designed with an email and password text inputs, and once the user enters those required credentials, I am supposed to authenticate that user(my idea: simply like passing the email and the password).
I have gone through many sample codes, but all of them were have done using graph API. I really wish your help. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there is a way to do what you want, but I do not recommend it.

Also, you probably mean Azure AD's OAuth / OpenId Connect endpoints and not Graph API.
Graph API is not used for authentication.

Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow allows you to pass username, password, client id, client secret and resource URI to get access tokens.

*The catch is that none of these work:*

- Users with MFA enabled
- Users with expired password
- Federated users (ADFS/Guest/MS account/Google account)

I recommend you don't make your own login page and instead use the MS login page.

If you want a more customizable identity provider and don't need access to O365 or the O365/Azure AD SSO, then you can use services like Azure AD B2C or Auth0.
You could even build your own with IdentityServer.

Comment: Thank you so much @juunas..!!! You saved my day.... Probably I need to do more research on the above factors you've mentioned. And again, thank you very much :) :)