# Login to Microsoft Graph JavaScript SDK using federated credential instead of client secret or certificate (application user)

Tags: azure, authentication, credentials, microsoft-graph-sdks, federated

How can we authenticate to Microsoft Graph using federated credentials and GitHub workflows?

I have registered an app in Azure Active Directory under 'App Registrations'. And I'm planning to use federated credentials (not client secret or certificate) in Azure App Registration to make Microsoft Graph API calls from GitHub Actions workflows. But in Microsoft documentation, I found only about how to authenticate using a client secret.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we authenticate a user in azure ad without using graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312893/can-we-authenticate-a-user-in-azure-ad-without-using-graph-api)

Comment: [Create federatedIdentityCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-federatedidentitycredentials?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript) and [Overview of federated identity credentials in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/federatedidentitycredentials-overview?view=graph-rest-beta)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out
FederatedIdentityCredentialRequest is available for beta API, could you please check out - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java/blob/c116f3062b6ea19bd86cd947fd1981a62654227b/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/requests/FederatedIdentityCredentialRequest.java

hope this will help you.

Thanks.